# Messing around with the derivative of $\int^{a}_x\tan x \, dx$,

Tags: calculus

Starting with
$$\int^{a}_x\tan x \, dx$$

Using integration by substitution $$\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = -\ln(\cos x)$$

I then take the primitive 
$$\int^{a}_x\tan x \, dx = [ -\ln(\cos x) ]_x^a$$

(I think this is where my mistake is)
$$= -\ln(\cos a)-(-\ln(\cos x)) = -\ln(\cos a)+\ln(\cos x)$$

Which i simplify into  $$\ln\left(\frac{\cos x}{\cos a}\right)$$

However, when I want to differentiate this to check my result, using the chain rule

$$u=\frac{\cos x}{\cos a}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{-\sin x}{\cos a}$$

$$ \frac{d}{dx} =\frac{d}{du}\ln(u)\cdot\frac{-\sin x}{\cos a}$$

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos a}{\cos x}\cdot\frac{-\sin x}{\cos a}=-\tan x$$

I don't understand where I went wrong, if someone has a pointer or a hint it would be much appreciated, also i am very sorry if there is any mistakes in the formatting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will help - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: No problem, you integrated from $x$ to $a$. The result is the negative of the integral from $a$ to $x$.

Comment: As André said, since the variable $x$ is the lower limit of the integral (instead of the upper limit), when you differentiate, you will get negative of the integrand, not positive.

Comment: I dislike your notation. You use x as dummy and the variable. It gives me chills.

Comment: So all I have to do is multiply it by -1 since the x is my lower limit?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. If it is $\int_x^a \tan t\,dt$, then you are sort of right, missing the constant of integration, also we need absolute values when the cosine is negative. If, as I suspect, this is supposed to be an example for the fundamental Theorem of Calculus, then yes, $\int_x^a f(t)\,dt=-\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: I was so concerned with the formatting that I didn't write out the questions properly. I apologize about that again. 

So the answer is correct apart from the absolute sign and constant of integration?